# How to choose among similar functions from different namespaces based on template parameter

Tags: c++

the title and the code is self-explanatory,

Is such a thing possible?how?

Is it encouraged? if not, what is the alternative?
thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace A
{
 void foo()
 {
   cout << "In A\n";
 }
}

namespace B
{
 void foo()
 {
  cout << "In B\n";
 }
}


template <typename X>
struct Foo {
    void foo()
    {
     X::foo();
    }
};


int main()
{

  Foo<A> _foo;
  _foo.foo();
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rename your member function, you can find it via ADL by using a proxy tag:

```
namespace A
{
    struct tag {};
     void foo(tag)
     {
         std::cout << "In A\n";
     }
}

namespace B
{
    struct tag {};
     void foo(tag)
     {
         std::cout << "In B\n";
     }
}

template<class Tag>
struct Foo {
    void fooADL()
    {
        foo(Tag{});
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<A::tag> f;
    f.fooADL();
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution, plus one!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a namespace as a template type (namespaces are not types); your code does not compile. The best you can hope for is to use [Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), but it won't work for functions taking no parameters.

Answer (score 2):

> Is such a thing possible?

No, you can't parametrise a namespace.

> if not, what is the alternative?

Use classes, rather than namespaces, to provide parametrisable scopes for the functions:

```
struct A {
    static void foo();
};

struct B {
    static void foo();
}
```

Comment: namespaces are not mine. I just need a way to call the correct function from among many namespaces. I didn't know how to do that. therefore I thought template might be able to help.